# Hyper-V machines, stuck at booting screen

Tags: hyper-v

Hi i have win2k8 sp1 machine, i have installed Hyper-V successfully to it.The virtualnetwork is set to external,i have a strange problem. Which ever virtual machine i use, either an existing VHD or boot to a new VHD using ISO, it gets stuck at the booting screen where the Microsoft Logo is on top and a green progress bar is running, it is happening with all OS's.. can any one help me out?

Comment: why should it be closed?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the RTM release of Hyper-V. KB950050.